# branch stall in classic 5-stage pipeline

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, pipelining

I'd appreciate, if anyone can answer my question regarding following exercise (not a homework, doing it for myself):

[**draw a pipeline cycle timing diagram for the above code. Start with the first lw before the loop, run one loop iteration, and stop at the first store of the second iteration.**](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~j2lau/cs141/final_review.html)

Well, I omitted the "above code", as you can see it in the table. "S" stands for stall. Below table is supposed to be a correct answer.

Question: why is there a stall in cycle 9 for a branch? It is just decode stage. As I understand, it doesn't need operand values yet.

I'd appreciate if anyone can comment...

```
instruction    1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lw r3, 0(r2)   f | d | x | m | w |   |   |   |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
sw r3, 0(r2)     | f | d | x | m | w |   |   |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
sub r1, r3, r4   |   | f | d | x | m | w |   |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
lw r3, 0(r1)     |   |   | f | d | x | m | w |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
sw r1, 0(r3)     |   |   |   | f | d | s | x | m | w  |    |    |    |    |    |
subi r2, r2, 4   |   |   |   |   | f | s | d | x | m  | w  |    |    |    |    |
bnez r2, loop    |   |   |   |   |   |   | f | s | d  | x  | m  | w  |    |    |
lw r3, 0(r2)     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | f  | d  | x  | m  | w  |    |
sw r3, 0(r2)     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |    | f  | d  | x  | m  | w  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says that the [classic 5-stage pipeline supposes that branches are resolved in decode stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Control_hazards), if they have no branch prediction or speculative execution.